# GetType() never equals typeof(List<string>)

Tags: c#, linq, query-string

I've run into an interesting comparison issue I'm having difficulty resolving, and I'd like help understanding why it's happening, what I can do to resolve it & most importantly: why I shouldn't be doing it like this at all & what I should be doing instead :P

I have the model shown below:

```cs
public class RouteUri
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<string> Destination { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

This is the usual format I expect to be parsing, however, there will be the odd time I need to expect `Destination` to be of type `string` and to handle this appropriately. This object needs to be processed into a URI, using the field name as the QueryString key for the value.

I've noticed that when I attempt to check the `Destination` field's type against `typeof(List<string>)` I can't seem to get an affirmative result.

Consider the following test method:

```cs
private static string ConvertRouteUriToUrl(DataStructures.RouteUri Url)
{
    var result = (from PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Url)
                  let test = new
                  {
                      property.Name,
                      property.DisplayName,
                      EqualityTest = property.GetType() == typeof(List<string>),
                      Property = property.GetValue(Url)?.GetType().Name,
                      Type = typeof(List<string>).Name
                  }
                  let value = property.GetType() == typeof(List<string>)
                      ? string.Join(",", property.GetValue(Url))
                      : (string)property.GetValue(Url)
                  where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
                  select property.Name.ToLower() + "=" + value
                  )
                  .ToList();

    return WebUtility.UrlEncode(string.Join("&", result));
}
```

Ignoring the "let value = " section & focusing on the "let test = " block of Linq, the line `EqualityTest = property.GetType()?.GetType() == typeof(List<string>)` will always return `false`, and appears to want to stay `false` no matter what comparison I put in there.

Obviously `Destination` is the only field that isn't a string, so all the other fields assign something similar to the below to `test`:

```
{
    Name = "Username",
    EqualityTest = false,
    Property = "String",
    Type = "List`1"
}
```

As expected, however when it comes to processing `Destination`, I'm seeing this:

```
{
    Name = "Destination",
    EqualityTest = false,
    Property = "List`1",
    Type = "List`1"
}
```

Why is this, is this a Linq anonymous type initialisation issue/feature?

I've tried many variations of this check but all of them have come back false thus-far, including attempting to match purely on strings; so I'd very much like to understand what is going on here.

Many thanks

---

Edit:

To answer the question I posed above, I believe the reason this was happening is due to the comparison operator I was using to compare the value returned from `.GetType().Name` with that returned from `typeof()`.

By using the `==` operator I was performing a comparison of object references, which compares instances of an object for equality. I should have been using `.Equals()` instead, which would have performed the comparison based on the value of each.

This is why, despite both objects outputting "List`1", they were never equal.

...

This is, of course, moot. As "Rand Random" mentions in the comments, I should have been using `.PropertyType` anyway.

Comment: Why the double `GetType()` - `property.GetType()?.GetType()` - what do you expect is the type of a type? - My guess is you are looking for `property.PropertyType` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `.GetType()?.GetType()` ???

Comment: Why not just have `Destination` as a `List<string>` with only one value when one Destination is provided?

Comment: use something like this var t = typeof(List<string>);
var t2 = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

Comment: and then do the comparison

Comment: @RandRandom That did it, I hadn't found that property. Thank you.